# Формат вывода ошибок валидатора Laravel

Tags: laravel

Я создал *Request* с правилами валидации для формы

```
class UserRegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // .....
            'somefield' => 'integer|min:2|max:64'
            // .....
        ];
    }
}
```

Все работает отлично, валидируется и в ответе от сервера получаю массив с ошибками

```
[
    'errors' => [
        // ....
        'somefield' => ['Поле должно быть числом!', 'Минимум 2 символа!']
    ]
]
```

Но мне хотелось бы перед тем как отдавать клиенту настроить формат, чтобы получилось следующее

```
[
    'errors' => [
        // ....
        'somefield' => 'Поле должно быть числом! <br> Минимум 2 символа!'
    ]
]
```

Вместо массива с ошибками получить уже готовую отформатированою строку. Каждый раз при валидации форм мне не очень хочется на клиенте писать цикл или какой-то костыль который будет приводить формат в порядок, хочется чтобы этим занимался сервер!

Comment: "\n" в коде и в стилях поставить "white-space: pre;". И все твои \n будут срабатывать как и <br>

Comment: @MoloF я же написал что формат вывода ошибок должен настраиватся на сервере. И у меня нет строки с "\n" у меня есть МАССИВ с ошибками которыый мне нужен как строка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение в статье [Laravel 5.5 вывод ошибок валидации для API](https://badcode.ru/laravel-5-5-vyvod-oshibok-validatsii-dlia-api/)

Правил файл `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Данный метод я переделал таким образом чтобы когда тип запроса `ajax` а также исключение `ValidationException` то я отадаю "свою версию" ответа. Код ниже!

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
        if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
            $format_errors = [];

            foreach ($exception->errors() as $k => $error) {
                $format_errors[$k] = implode('<br>', $error);
            }

            $json = [
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
                'errors' => $format_errors,
            ];

            return response()->json($json, 400);
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
foreach($errors as &$error) {
    $error = implode('<br>', $error);
};
```

Comment: Спасибо однако, но это не то что я хотел. Я нашел решение на просторах интернета, сейчас поделюсь.